# Comparing dates of values in 2 dataframes to decide output

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is DataFrame 1:

```
Date    Serial Number   Type
0   2014-12-17  1N4AL2EP8DC270200   New
1   2015-10-28  1N4AL2EP8DC270200   Used
2   2015-01-22  1N4AL3AP1EN239307   New
3   2015-11-22  1N4AL3AP1EN239307   Used
4   2015-05-22  1N4AL3AP1FC235402   New
5   2016-12-02  1N4AL3AP1FC235402   Used
6   2015-01-22  1N4AL3AP2FC213098   New
7   2016-05-13  1N4AL3AP2FC213098   Used
8   2014-05-14  1N4AL3AP3EC132416   New
9   2016-04-07  1N4AL3AP3EC132416   Used
10  2014-05-24  1N4AL3AP5EC316644   New
11  2014-12-18  1N4AL3AP5EC316644   Used
12  2014-12-11  1N4AL3AP6EC322517   New
13  2015-10-04  1N4AL3AP6EC322517   Used
14  2016-06-06  1N4AL3AP6EC322517   Used
...
```

This is DataFrame 2:

```
    Date    Serial Number
0   2014-03-12  5N1AA08C78N611573
1   2014-03-12  JN8AS5MT3EW604277
2   2014-03-12  1N6AF0LX5DN114710
3   2014-03-12  1N4AL3AP8DN447876
4   2014-03-12  JN8AZ1MU8AW021145
5   2014-03-12  JN1AZ4EH0AM500138
6   2014-03-12  JN8AF5MR3BT013548
7   2014-03-12  3N1AB61E17L629049
8   2014-03-12  3N1BC13E87L368844
9   2014-03-13  1N6AD07W95C431183
10  2014-03-13  1N6AA07A25N543180
11  2014-03-13  1N4CL2AP1BC110185
12  2014-03-13  JN8AZ1MW1BW181306
13  2014-03-13  5N1BV28U46N116791
...
```

Just given a sample of the DataFrame, not the entire DataFrame. I need to retrieve the first Date of every Serial Number that has its type as Used in DataFrame 1 (For example: For serial number '1N4AL3AP6EC322517' 2015-10-04 is the Date I'm looking for. Then compare this Date to the Date recorded for the same Serial Number in DataFrame 2 if the Date in DataFrame 2 is earlier that in DataFrame 1, mark it with 'A' otherwise mark it with 'B'.

Have to do this for over 2000 serial numbers, what's an efficient way to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
print (df2)
         Date      Serial Number
0  2016-03-12  1N4AL3AP6EC322517
1  2013-03-12  1N4AL3AP5EC316644
2  2014-03-12  1N4AL3AP3EC132416
3  2016-08-12  1N4AL3AP2FC213098
4  2014-03-12  JN8AZ1MU8AW021145

#if necessary cast Date columns to datetime
df1.Date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date)
df2.Date = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)
#get first value of column Serial Number filtered by Used
df = df1[df1.Type == 'Used'].drop_duplicates(['Serial Number'])
print (df)
         Date      Serial Number  Type
1  2015-10-28  1N4AL2EP8DC270200  Used
3  2015-11-22  1N4AL3AP1EN239307  Used
5  2016-12-02  1N4AL3AP1FC235402  Used
7  2016-05-13  1N4AL3AP2FC213098  Used
9  2016-04-07  1N4AL3AP3EC132416  Used
11 2014-12-18  1N4AL3AP5EC316644  Used
13 2015-10-04  1N4AL3AP6EC322517  Used

#add value B
df2['Mark'] = 'B'
df = pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values(['Date']), 
                   df2.sort_values(['Date']), on='Date', by='Serial Number')
print (df)
        Date      Serial Number  Type Mark
0 2014-12-18  1N4AL3AP5EC316644  Used    B
1 2015-10-04  1N4AL3AP6EC322517  Used  NaN
2 2015-10-28  1N4AL2EP8DC270200  Used  NaN
3 2015-11-22  1N4AL3AP1EN239307  Used  NaN
4 2016-04-07  1N4AL3AP3EC132416  Used    B
5 2016-05-13  1N4AL3AP2FC213098  Used  NaN
6 2016-12-02  1N4AL3AP1FC235402  Used  NaN
```

```
#add value A
mask = df['Serial Number'].isin(df2['Serial Number'])
df.loc[mask, 'Mark'] = df.loc[mask, 'Mark'].fillna('A')
print (df)
        Date      Serial Number  Type Mark
0 2014-12-18  1N4AL3AP5EC316644  Used    B
1 2015-10-04  1N4AL3AP6EC322517  Used    A
2 2015-10-28  1N4AL2EP8DC270200  Used  NaN
3 2015-11-22  1N4AL3AP1EN239307  Used  NaN
4 2016-04-07  1N4AL3AP3EC132416  Used    B
5 2016-05-13  1N4AL3AP2FC213098  Used    A
6 2016-12-02  1N4AL3AP1FC235402  Used  NaN
```